# Starting Windows Media Player with .Net

Tags: .net, process

I'm trying to start windows media player from my .net applciation.

Previously in .Net 4.8 the following code worked fine:

```
Process.Start("wmplayer.exe", this.UnderlyingAudioFile.FullName);
```

now with .Net the following error arises upon call:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified.'

any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error message is misleading.
The error was actually that Binary reader blocks the File for other threads.

make sure to open the file giving file access to other threads such as:

```
this.Reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.Read));
```